# How to test for a range of inconsistent values

Tags: python, testing, numbers, range

I need to test in python if `x` equals a series on inconsistent numbers
for example `1, 2, 7, 9, 32, 98`

Is their something I can use that wouldn't take forever? I know I could type

```
if x == 1 or x== 2 or x ==7 or x== 9 ...:
    [code here]
```

is there a quicker way to type this in the Python syntax?

Comment: I mean they could be any numbers and there is no pattern between them

Answer (score 1):

```
if x in [1, 2, 7, 9, ...]:
    [code here]
```